# JPA Criteria with Join against self with primitive types

Tags: java, jpa

I have an entity that looks like

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "log_entry")
public class LogItem {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "request_id", nullable = false)
    private String requestId;

    @Column(name = "request_type")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private RequestType requestType;

    @Column(name = "entry_type")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private LogType logType;

    @Column(name = "operation_name")
    private String operationName;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "time_stamp", nullable = false)
    private Date timeStamp;

    @Column(name = "attr_1")
    private String attr1;

    @Column(name = "attr_2")
    private String attr2;
    // ...
    @Column(name = "attr_10")
    private String attr10;
}
```

This maps to a table that holds audit records, typically there would be one root row and a bunch of rows inserted with the same requestId with varying logType, requestType and operationName values.  The attrX columns hold different values depending on the types/operations involved.

I need to implement a generic query tool that can find say find the root request and one or more specific child element depending on the values of attrs.  However, I'm struggling to simply join the log table to itself.

The bit I'm stuck at is trying to emulate the following:

```
SELECT l1.*, l2.* FROM log_entry l1
  JOIN log_entry l2 
    ON l2.request_id = l1.request_id  
   AND l2.entry_type = 'Something'
   AND l2.operation_name = 'someOperation'
 WHERE l2.operation_name = 'someOtherOperation'
```

This is my code

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<LogItem[]> criteria = cb.createQuery(LogItem[].class);
Root<LogItem> root = criteria.from(LogItem.class);
Join<LogItem, LogItem> responseJoin = 
        root.join(LogItem.requestId.getName(), JoinType.INNER);

ArrayList<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
// Simply adds preciates for log type etc... 
getCommonPredicates(filter, cb, root, predicates);
// Add predicates for attr values
addAttributePredicates(cb, predicates, filter.getAttributeFilters());

criteria.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
TypedQuery<LogItem[]> query = entityManager.createQuery(criteria);
List<LogItem[]> resultsList = query.getResultList();
```

This however gives me the error:

*org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.BasicPathUsageException: Cannot join to attribute of basic type*

I understand I could get around this by adding LogItem references to the entity class but I can't modify the table structure.  Is there a way to do this without reverting to JBDC?  The SQL is trivial I just can't see how to transform it into a criteria.   I'm using hibernate, while I would prefer a JPA solution I'm not adverse to using hibernate specific code.

Comment: and what has log_item got to do with log_entry ?

Comment: Sorry, typo I typed the entity annotations rather than copy and paste.  Only one entity involved.

Comment: obviously you cannot use JOIN on a non-relation field, as per all docs. You could add another from() class, and add a where clause.

Comment: Thanks, I hoped I had missed something but guess not.  I was was hoping to use a join as sometimes I will need to do an outer join for cases where there was a failure and there are no followup records, I guess I'll just have to handle that separately.  If you want to add an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only `join` via a 1-1/1-N/M-N/N-1 relation, since JPA tries to keep to the spirit of O-O. Your alternatives here are

- Add an extra `from` clause and specify a `where` clause to accompany
  it. This likely will create a CROSS JOIN.
- Add a relation to your model so then you can use `join`() and define INNER or LEFT OUTER.

Clearly some of these may not be an option for your situation.

Comment: In some cases a `Subquery` may also be an alternative to a `JOIN`.